# Django URLs: matching a fixed number of optional parameters?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I'd like to match URLs of the following form in my Django URL dispatcher:

```
 /(?P<location>\w+)-holidays/in-(?P<month>\w+)/to-(?P<top_price>\d+)
```

The complicated bit is that I'd like any of the three separate elements of the path to be optional. So I'd like to match all of the following:

```
 /venice-holidays
 /venice-holidays/in-june/
 /venice-holidays/in-june/to-1000
 /venice-holidays/to-1000
 /in-june
 /in-june/to-1000
 /to-1000
```

Can I do this with Django URL patterns? Sorry if this is a duplicate, I've done some searching but couldn't find exactly this question.

UPDATE: I plan to check that `location` and `month` etc are valid within the view, rather than providing patterns for them in the URL.

Comment: THis is not that complicated. Just split against `/` and check each element in turn.

Comment: You mean treat the whole thing as a single string, and process it in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a similar thing, I solved it like this:

**url.py:**

```
url(r'^(?P<location>[\w]+)/(?P<month>[\w]*)/?(?P<something>[\w]*)/?', ...),
```

**views.py:**

```
def course_list(request, location, month = None, something = None):

    if month:
        # do stuff
```

You really want to have a "base path word" as first item in your url.

If you do this:

```
url(r^(?P<location>[\w]*) ... ),
```

That will match all urls pretty much